# C++ network stream

Tags: c++

I am a newbie using C++ and I have a background with Java

I am working on a simple linux server using c++ and I have a question about converting byte data.

In Java, I can use putShort, or putString in ByteBuffer and simply send the buffer over socket using byteBuffer.array()

What is the corresponding c++ code of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ itself does not have networking builtin. You might want to skim through the [boost libraries](http://boost.org). Install them, they are common, and read the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard library does not include networking facilities. However the famous boost libraries do include this in the form of [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html). The documentation includes several [examples of use](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).

[`boost::asio::mutable_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html) or [`boost::asio::basic_streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_streambuf.html) seem similar to what you describe.